# Creating multiple tuples in multiple tables

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, foreign-keys, tuples

I have a question on creating multiple tuples in multiple tables using Java.

Here are my tables.

```
create table department(

dept_name       varchar(20) primary key, 
building        varchar(15), 
budget      numeric(12,2)
);

create table student
(ID             int, 
 name           varchar(20) not null, 
 dept_name      varchar(20), 
 tot_cred       numeric(10,0),
 primary key (ID),
 foreign key (dept_name) references department(dept_name)
);
```

And what I am trying to accomplish is that the java program will prompt the user with

"How many tuples would you like in the Department Table?"
User: 1000.
"1000 tuples created in the Department table."

"How many Tuples would you like in the student table?"
User: 500.
"500 tuples created in the student table."

Now I can insert one tuple into department so say

```
"Insert into department ('CSI', 'TownHall', '120000')";
```

Then from here I do a

```
 Insert into student (id, name, dept_name,tot_cred)
             select '"+counts+"', 'Student"+counts+"', dept_name, '10' 
             from department      
             where    dept_name='CSI'.
```

Counts++ is in the while loop so there isn't duplicate PK's.

So I can create 10000 Tuples in the student table, but I cant create more than 1 tuple in the Department table because CSI can't be duplicated.

But if I don't insert atleast one tuple in the department table then I lose the Foreign key constraint.

Any thoughts?

PS. I'm not here for you guys to just do code just need an idea

Brandon

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having dept_name as a `primary key`, create another column `DEPT_ID` and set it as a primary key. You can increment that in the same way.

Also, consider using a [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) for your SQL updates

As a rule, your FK would point to the PK of another table. So when you have created DEPT_ID as a primary key, you would also need to modify your student schema to reflect this change

**Edit:** Based on your requirement, you can do something like this (although I don't know your exact requirement) & assuming the aforementioned change, you can do something like this

Create a `PreparedStatement` like this:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(INSERT INTO student(id, name, dept_id,tot_cred) values(?,?,?,?)");
```

Since you know the number of departments that you've, you can now create a loop to insert tuples into your department table and then use this information to insert into your student table, right? (*This sounds more like a homework, so I would leave it to you to think of how to do this part*)

Comment: Yea So I did that. But I can only create as many student tuples as there are department tuples.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I hope this helps you with some pointers in the right direction.

Comment: Yes it is a programming assign and your right I don't expect to much info I would like to accomplish this. I am going to try this PreparedStatement and look further into this.