# MySQL/JAVA Inserting Speed

Tags: java, mysql, insert, tuples, execution-time

So I am developing in Net Beans a MySQL/Java program for class that helps us understand execution time and such.

So I created the java program so that a user can enter x amount of Tuples into each of the 6 tables. And so we have to enter data up too 125000 tuples. Well I only got to the problem with 60000 tuples, and when the program is executing it takes around 30 minutes just to insert the 60000 tuples.

Needless to say eventually I will have to enter 125000 tuples into a table and I need to know how to make this insert faster? Any Ideas?

Thank You

Brandon

Edit:

Code

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package program2;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Random;


public class Program2 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

            // Variables
            int takesnum=0;
            int instructornum=0;
            int coursenum = 0;
            int studentnum = 0;
            int count = 0;
            int departmentnum =0;
            int counts= 0;
            int minimum=0;
            int x=0;
            int teachesnum=0;
            // Variables

            //Connection to the database
            Connection conn = null;
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
            String dbName = "university2";
            String Driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            // Change the userName & password to what ever your credentials are.
            String userName = "root"; 
            String password = "121089bn";
            //Connection to the database

       try {

            InputStreamReader istream = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            BufferedReader MyReader = new BufferedReader(istream);

            Class.forName(Driver).newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
            System.out.println("Connected");

            // Ask the user how many tuples in department table.
            System.out.println("How many tuples would you like to create in Department Table?");

            // Takes in as string the number then parse it to an int.
            String dept = MyReader.readLine();
            departmentnum = Integer.parseInt(dept);

// ****************** Department Table ******************//  
            while (count < departmentnum)
            {
                Statement st = conn.createStatement();
                // Counts keeps the counter so the Primary Key is unique.
                st.executeUpdate("Insert into department (dept_name, building, budget) values ('Dept "+counts+"', 'Voigt', '1200')");
                count++;
                counts++;
            }

// ****************** Student Table ******************//                
            count=0;
            counts=0;

            System.out.println("How many tuples would you like to create in Student Table?");
            String student = MyReader.readLine();
            studentnum = Integer.parseInt(student);

            while (count < studentnum)
            {
                int z=0;
                int credit=128;
                Random ran = new Random(); 
                int range = departmentnum - minimum; 
                x =  ran.nextInt(range) + minimum; 

                Random random = new Random(); 
                int totcred = credit - minimum; 
                z =  random.nextInt(totcred) + minimum; 

                Statement st = conn.createStatement();
                st.executeUpdate("Insert into student (id, name, dept_name,tot_cred) select '"+counts+"', 'Student "+counts+"', dept_name, '"+z+"' from department where dept_name='Dept "+x+"'");
                count++;
                counts++;
            }

// ****************** Course Table ******************//                 
            x=0;
            count=0;
            counts=0;   

            System.out.println("How many tuples would you like to create in Course Table?");
            String course = MyReader.readLine();
            coursenum = Integer.parseInt(course);

            while (count < coursenum)
            {
                Random ran = new Random(); 
                int range = departmentnum - minimum; 
                x =  ran.nextInt(range) + minimum; 
                int credit=5;
                int z=0;

                Random random = new Random(); 
                int totcred = credit - minimum; 
                z =  random.nextInt(totcred) + minimum; 

                Statement st = conn.createStatement();
                st.executeUpdate("Insert into course (course_id, title, dept_name,credits) select '"+counts+"', 'Computer Science "+counts+"', dept_name, '"+z+"' from department where dept_name='Dept "+x+"'");
                count++;
                counts++;
            }

// ****************** Instructor Table ******************//                   
            x=0;
            count=0;
            counts=0;   

            System.out.println("How many tuples would you like to create in Instructor Table?");
            String instructor = MyReader.readLine();
            instructornum = Integer.parseInt(instructor);

            while (count < instructornum)
            {
                Random ran = new Random(); 
                int range = departmentnum - minimum; 
                x =  ran.nextInt(range) + minimum; 

                Statement st = conn.createStatement();
                st.executeUpdate("Insert into instructor (id, name, dept_name,salary) select '"+counts+"', 'Instructor "+counts+"', dept_name, '10000' from department where dept_name='Dept "+x+"'");
                count++;
                counts++;

            }

// ****************** Teaches Table ******************//                    
            x=0;
            count=0;
            counts=0;

            System.out.println("How many tuples would you like to create in Teaches Table?");
            String teaches = MyReader.readLine();
            teachesnum = Integer.parseInt(teaches);

            while (count < teachesnum)
            {
                Random ran = new Random(); 
                int range = instructornum - minimum; 
                x =  ran.nextInt(range) + minimum; 

                Random random = new Random(); 
                int courserange = coursenum - minimum; 
                int y =  random.nextInt(courserange) + minimum; 

                int g = 100;
                Random r = new Random();
                int f = g - minimum;
                int h = r.nextInt(f) + minimum;

                int l = 100;
                Random random1 = new Random();
                int j = l - minimum;
                int k = random1.nextInt(j) + minimum;


                Statement st = conn.createStatement();
                st.executeUpdate("Insert into teaches (id, course_id, semester, year) select id, course_id, 'Spr "+h+"', '20"+k+"' from course, instructor where instructor.id='"+x+"' and course.course_id='"+y+"'");
                count++;
                counts++;
            }

// ****************** Takes Table ******************//                    
            x=0;
            count=0;
            counts=0;

            System.out.println("How many tuples would you like to create in Takes Table?");
            String takes = MyReader.readLine();
            takesnum = Integer.parseInt(takes);

            while (count < takesnum)
            {
                Random ran = new Random(); 
                int range = studentnum - minimum; 
                x =  ran.nextInt(range) + minimum; 

                Random random = new Random(); 
                int courserange = coursenum - minimum; 
                int y =  random.nextInt(courserange) + minimum;

                int g = 100;
                Random r = new Random();
                int f = g - minimum;
                int h = r.nextInt(f) + minimum;

                int l = 100;
                Random random1 = new Random();
                int j = l - minimum;
                int k = random1.nextInt(j) + minimum;

                Statement st = conn.createStatement();
                st.executeUpdate("Insert into takes (id, course_id, semester, year, grade) select id, course_id, 'Spr "+h+"', '20"+k+"', 'B' from course, student where student.id='"+x+"' and course.course_id='"+y+"'");
                count++;
                counts++;
            }

            conn.close();
       }

            catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
}
}
```

Tables

```
drop database university2;
create database university2;

use university2;

create table department
(dept_name      varchar(20) primary key, 
 building       varchar(15), 
 budget             numeric(12,2)
);

create table student
(ID             int,
 name           varchar(20) not null, 
 dept_name      varchar(20), 
 tot_cred       numeric(10,0),
 primary key (ID),
 foreign key (dept_name) references department(dept_name)

);

create table course
(course_id      int, 
 title          varchar(50), 
 dept_name      varchar(15),
 credits        numeric(2,0),
 primary key (course_id),
 foreign key (dept_name) references department(dept_name)
);



create table instructor
(ID         int, 
 name           varchar(20) not null, 
 dept_name      varchar(20), 
 salary         numeric(8,2),
 primary key (ID),
 foreign key (dept_name) references department(dept_name)
);

create table teaches
(ID         int, 
 course_id      int,
 semester       varchar(6),
 year           numeric(4,0),
 primary key (ID, course_id, semester, year),
 foreign key (course_id) references course(course_id)
    on delete cascade,
 foreign key (ID) references instructor(ID)
    on delete cascade
);


create table takes
(ID         int, 
 course_id      int,
 semester       varchar(6),
 year           numeric(4,0),
 grade              varchar(2),
 primary key (ID, course_id, semester, year),
 foreign key (course_id) references course(course_id)
    on delete cascade,
 foreign key (ID) references student(ID)
    on delete cascade
);
```

Comment: You could be experiencing slow insertion speeds for many (many) reasons. We need to see some code and how your mySQL database is set up.

Comment: You can try disabling autommit to avoid each insert being commited individually. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setAutoCommit(boolean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having had a too close look at your code, here's a few things you might want to look at :

1. `PreparedStatement` will probably help a bit, as the statement doesn't have to be compiled for every request.
2. Execute statements in batches. Have a look at the addBatch() method on PreparedStatement. Once you've added, say, 1000 batches, you can execute them using executeBatch(). If you do this in conjunction with the setting '[rewriteBatchedStatements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html)' on the connection, then the MySQL driver might be able to do some optimisations.
3. Introduce several "insert" workers, which each is responsible for inserting batches of a given size. If you're only working with a single connection, you need to do one insert at a time. If you work with multiple connections (via multiple threads) you'll most likely see an increase in speed.

Comment: Yes I am looking into PreparedStatement right now. Most Examples I see enter data for each indivual column. Any links or example to transfer from a statement to PreparedStatement

Answer (score 1):

Use a `PreparedStatement` instead of an `Statement`. It "precompiles" the SQL, making succesive calls to it way faster.

Comment: So how would you make the changes to what I have. Maybe just on the Department Section.

Comment: You already have an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633443/creating-multiple-tuples-in-multiple-tables.